# How to duplicate specific lines in Python

Tags: python

```
import sys
from math import log
import datetime
import numpy as np
from itertools import repeat


x = 1 
y = 2 

z= 24

T=int(z/(x+y))

with open('A.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('A.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i==10:
                f.write(str("Papa")+'\n')
                f.write(str(x)+ "*31 /"+'\n')
                f.write(str("Mama")+'\n')
                f.write(str(y)+ "*31 /"+'\n')
                [x for item in lines for x in repeat(item, T)]
        else:
                f.write(line)
        previous_line = line
```

This is my code, it runs fine without any errors but it doesnt give me any results

I am trying to achieve duplicating the lines depending on T, since T here is equal to 8, so the output would look like:

```
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
```

How can I make the code works like this?

Comment: what is the content of A.txt before you write to it?

Comment: Write a loop over `range(T)`....

Comment: The value of `[x for item in lines for x in repeat(item, T)]` is never used.

Comment: Indentation issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the list comprehension. Use a loop

```
if i==10:
    for _ in range(T):
        f.write('Papa\n{}*31 /\nMama\n{}*31 /\n'.format(x, y))
```

Alternatively, you were looking for

```
item = """Papa
{}*31 /
Mama
{}*31 /""".format(x, y) 

for x in repeat(item, T):
    f.write(x)
```

Or better

```
f.writelines(repeat(item, T))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I got this error     f.write(x)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file., and when I comment the second paragraph of your answer, it runs without any error but it doesnt update the file

Comment: Sounds like you are copied my answer outside of the indentation of a `with open` block

Comment: Hi, thanks it works, I have one last question, how do you make it remove the old one and re-write the new one ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "respond". If this doesn't work, your file is empty to begin with, and there's nothing to `enumerate` over, or there are not 11 lines in the initial file

Comment: Remove what "old one"? You're already overwriting the file with new content.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import repeat

x = 1 
y = 2 

z= 24

T=int(z/(x+y))

# dont have your file, creating a dummy data read in
if lines is None:
    lines = list(map(str,range(20)))

with open('A.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i==10:

            # create the text and write it into the file 
            # using repeat it and writelines (writes multiple lines at once) 
            f.writelines(repeat(f'Papa\n{x}*31\nMama\n{y}*31\n',T)) 
        else:
            f.write(line+"\n")

with open('A.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        print(l, end = "")
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Comment: @cricket_007 nice one, did not know that :) - incoperated

Comment: I keep getting invalid syntax at n' , I tried to fix it but couldnt

Comment: it comes as invalid syntax at the line (f.writelines(repeat(f'Papa\n{x}*31\nMama\n{y}*31\n',T)), at the end where (') it highlighted

Comment: @Rory you are probably not running python 3.6 - the string interpolation syntax ( `f'text{variablename}'` ) was introduced. Try the older format syntax, that should work down to 2.7 or so : `f.writelines(repeat("Papa\n{}*31\nMama\n{}*31\n".format(x,y),T))`

Comment: i am running 3.4.3

Comment: Doing it with 3.4 repeats it twice '1







2







3



Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31
Papa
1*31
Mama
2*31


4







5







Papa

1*31

Mama

2*31

Papa

1*31

Mama

2*31

Papa

1*31

Mama

2*31

Papa

1*31

Mama

2*31

Papa

1*31

Mama

2*31

Papa

1*31

Mama

2*31

Papa

1*31

Mama

2*31

Papa

1*31

Mama

2*31
7
8
9'

Comment: Instead of having 8, it will be 16, Any suggestions how to not to do that?

Comment: @Rory The amount depends on T - it is calculated from  `T=int(z/(x+y))` - make `z,x and y` so it works as you want it. Please read [How to debug small programs (#4)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and try to debug your program. You can inspect the values and better unserstand how it works.